# Override styles for EditText in Android

Tags: android, styles, android-edittext

I need to override styles for two EditText instances. I have two issues regarding this:

1) One EditText is for entering a password but with the same typeface. If I delete password=true it works. By default typeface=sans.

```
<style name="customEdit" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:password">true</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">serif</item>  //doesn work.
</style>
```

2) Both fields have hints. And I need to set the color of these hints; is it possible? I didn't find something like this: android:hintColor...

```
<item name="android:textColor">#acacac</item> //works for text only.
```

I tried two variants for password type:

- android:inputType="textPassword"
- android:password=true

Both change typeface to default automaticaly, even in the "UI Constructor".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For your second problem, this can be helpful(under the EditText tag):

```
        android:textColorHint="#3b64a8"
```

In your Activity:

```
    passwordText.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF);
    passwordText.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());
```

here  "passwordText" is the EditText for password.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately the answer to the password did not work.

Comment: ok, rather than in xml file , you can set the typeface for Password type edit text in your activity. see the edit in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

This should work, Try it

```
<style name="customEdit" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
        <item name="android:inputType">textPassword</item>
        <item name="android:password">true</item>
        <item name="android:typeface">serif</item> 
        <item name="android:textColorHint=">#F28EC1</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>         
    </style>
```